# is it possible to access web application from another server programtically

Tags: 2013, permissions

if I have full control rights on a SharePoint 2013 Web application which resides on another server, is it possible to access that web application on my server programmatically? for example can I access the list of that web application in my c# program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can but it has to be via [the Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912%28v=office.15%29.aspx), not the server Object Model.

[Client Object Model for managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060%28v=office.15%29.aspx#ClientManagedOM)

Strictly speaking, the above answers your question. But if you add more detail I could be more specific.

[What the CSOM does and does not do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163082.aspx)

Comment: actually I was trying to move document libraries between sites, site coll, web applications. I m successful in doing that. so I was trying it between web application between 2 servers

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I would say that the easy way is likely to download the content and then create an exact replica of the library inside of a web site in the new web application. The code will be very similar to Server OM, but there are a number of limitations to the Client OM you should make yourself aware of as well. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: i want to keep metadata as it is.downloading the content wl not retain metadata.also i want this to be done in SSOM.i want to move the libraries at run time

Comment: If your web applications are in different farms on different servers, then this is just not possible with SSOM.